# Unexpected token => on async using Firebase Functions (2022) default ESlint

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions, eslint

My package.json

```html
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.21.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My .eslintrc.js

```html
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

A scrubbed version of my index.js

```html
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (input) => {
    // my code here
})
```

Error from terminal

```html
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

**I'm thinking that the ESLint version that is being applied may be out of date? If so, how do I update it? Do I need to use a babel-eslint package (or newer)? Do I need to apply ES7 or 8 rules instead, and how?**

Answer (score 1):

I updated my .eslintrc.js file

```html
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

This way, `es6` was removed as a true value in `env`, and `parserOptions` was added with `ecmaVersion` set to `latest` release. I then just applied the rules based on the failed items. It works, but was a bit of a hassle. I suppose the code is cleaner at least...

Answer (score 0):

You've only enabled `es6: true`. However, `async` functions are part of ES8 (ES2017). You'll want to use something more modern than ES6. Alternatively, set the [parser options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options) specifically.